# How to Navigate to the main Page on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-8.1, frame

please, can you tell me how to use `Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));` to go to the main Page from any Page closing all pages in stack?

I tried to use this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Frame.BackStack.Count; i++)
{
    Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(i);
}
Frame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage));
```

But doesn't work, because when I press the back key button the pages however open.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to have the complete back stack gone, just use

```
Frame.BackStack.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

First navigate to MainPage then clear the backstack

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
Frame.BackStack.Clear();
```